# Does MapInfo License Server run on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: mapinfo

The documentation for MapInfo License Server Utility (v4.5) advises that it has been tested on Windows Server 2012.

I need to know whether the LSU runs on Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

We, Pitney Bowes, basically do not know as we haven't tested the License Server Utility on that OS (Windows Server 2012 R2).

On the other hand we aren't saying that it will not run on Windows Server 2012 R2.

If that's the server software you have available, I would give it a try and see how it works.

Not a direct answer, but that the best advice I can give